# Finding a formula for the kth partial sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, telescopic-series

I need help finding the kth partial sum of the question below:

> Consider the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ where $a_n=\ln\left(\frac{6n-1}{6n+5}\right)$. Find a formula, in closed form, for the $k^{th}$ partial sum $s_k$.

I think this is a telescoping series but I'm sorta lost on how to answer the question. Any help would be appreciated

[Picture of Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VnlA.png)

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: ln(5/(6k+5))...

Comment: Agree with mag, @wewewe132 please check https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020

Comment: That link may be a bit overwhelming. Here are some shorter intros to MathJax: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation & https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/33183/207316

Comment: @PM2Ring : good point. It's the first time I try to point someone to some Mathjax resources, I took the first one that popped out of google. Thanks for those links, bookmarked now.

Comment: @user3733558 No worries. We've had some recent discussions on meta about making it easier for newcomers to start learning MathJax. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33103/207316 and there are various other recent posts on https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathjax that you might like to look at.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{aligned}a_n \;=\;& \ln\left(\frac{6n-1}{6n+5}\right) \;=\; \ln(6n-1) \;-\; \ln(6n+5) \\[5mm] =\;& \ln(6n-1) \;-\; \ln(6(n+1)-1)\end{aligned}$$

Which means that $\sum a_n$ is a telescoping sum, giving us:

$$\sum^n_{k=1}a_k \;=\; \ln(5) \;-\; \ln(6(n+1)-1)$$

Comment: When $n=2$, your final expression reads as $a_1+a_2=a_1-a_2$. Looks weird to me.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I changed it

Comment: Now I agree, +1 :)

Comment: Sounded right in my head; obviously wasn't. I guess thinking of it as "all but first and last cancel" can lead to some confusion